# Django abstract class with legacy database

Tags: django, django-models

Assume I have three tables (duck, Goose, and Rooster) in a legacy, but still active, database. There is a 3rd-party application that owns this schema and adds/updates/deletes the entries on a regular basis, I have read-only access.  The PKs in Duck, Goose, and Rooster are guaranteed to be unique, even between tables.

I'd like to have a super class (Bird) that I could use as a ForeignKey to any of these three tables.

Here's where I'm stuck:

- I can't create an abstract class that Duck, Goose and Rooster inherit from because django doesn't support ForeignKeys to abstract classes
- I can't create a fully-populated Bird model unless I want to duplicate the relevant data from the subclasses every time there's a change (countless timing issues)
- I can't change the Duck, Goose, and Rooster tables into a single table because it's the other applications active schema

My best solution at this point is to use a Bird abstract class but ignore the Django API. Instead of using a ForeignKey to bird, I'd just include the unique PK.  Whenever I need the actual object, I'd use some helper functions like "getBirdByPK()" that checks all three subclasses.

This is very un-pythonic and I don't like that the helper function would need to know about every subclass.

Any better suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your use case but it sounds like [generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) might be able to help you.